# Start new thread within Async Task

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Is it possible start a new thread within an Async task?
Something like this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

protected ProgressBar progBar;
protected Intent intent;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    progBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.start_progressBar);
    progBar.setProgress(0);
    new StartingApp().execute();
}

protected class StartingApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    int myProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myProgress = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while(myProgress<50){
            myProgress++;
            publishProgress(myProgress);
                SystemClock.sleep(10);
            }

        MyRunnableClass mrc = new MyRunnableClass();
        mrc.run();

        return null;    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

        intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        progBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
}
```

MyRunnableClass is a class which implements Runnable.
I want something like this because in the first activity I want to show a progress bar while the application is initializing (fill data structures, starting threads).

Another question I have is: should I use the run() or start() method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't get a new Thread if you just `run()` a `Runnable`. You have to do `(new Thread(mrc)).start();` and yes it is possible but why would you want to have a thread in a thread?

Comment: You don't have a progress. Your are just simulating a progress. Maybe you should use a indeterminate progressbar.

Comment: @zapl So when I use `run()` or `start()` for a `Runnable` class, what I am doing exactly? My idea was use an AsnycTask to start worker threads used during the lifecycle of the application and then change to next activity...

Comment: @207 I know I am just simulating the progress, but for now this is not the main problem... But thanks for the suggestion. Maybe I will use indeterminate progress bar, because in fact I don't know the length of the task.

Comment: @amp when you `run()` it then the code is just executed directly in the thread you are in. It's just a method named run, nothing more. And your thread is working until `run` is completed. If you `start()` a thread then nothing happens in your thread except you call a method (that is immediately finished). But that creates a thread in which the code is then executed (the new Thread automatically calls `run`).

Comment: @zapl Even if the class `implements Runnable`, if I don't start a new thread with `new Thread(mrc).start()`, this class is like other "normal" class, am I right?

Comment: yep, `implements Runnable` just means that the class has a `run()` method. You can use that class now to run the `run()` in a Thread but it's still just a normal method. The `Runnable` interface is there so Thread knows that there is a `run()` method which it can call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do that? 
As pointed out in the code you need to call new Thread(mrc).start() to make it work. Otherwise i dont see any problem in that code spawning a new thread.

Comment: Like zapl said, it should be this way... Thanks!